# Stream "RETURNING" from insert for pg-promise

Tags: node.js, stream, pg-promise

The goal here is to stream the `RETURNING` data from `INSERT INTO ....` to a write stream.

ie.

```js
                const write_stream = fs.createWriteStream('file.csv')
                client.query(`
                    INSERT INTO table1  (columns) 
                        SELECT ...
                        FROM table2
                        RETURNING *
                    `)
                    .then(returned => {
                        returned.rows.pipe(write_stream)                      
                    })
```

Is this possible with `pg-promise`?

At the moment the response from `returned.rows` contains all the data in an array[{}] thus above example does not work, so the only solution might need to be an insert and a select separately, but would be great if I could simply get the returned data.

Comment: [Streaming from database](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#from-database).

Comment: If the answer I gave you (5 days ago) works for you, then please accept it, or else comment if there is any issue. (I'm the author if `pg-promise`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing the right answer, as the question author chose not to follow [the example provided](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#from-database).

Here's how to stream query results into a csv file properly (from the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)):

```
import QueryStream from 'pg-query-stream';
import CsvWriter from 'csv-write-stream';
import {createWriteStream} from 'fs';

const csv = new CsvWriter();
const file = createWriteStream('out.csv');

const qs = new QueryStream('select * from my_table');

await db.stream(qs, s => {
    s.pipe(csv).pipe(file);
});
//=> resolves with: {processed, duration}
```

See [stream](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#stream) method.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why I didn't think of this but the solution is simply using `pg-query-stream`

```js
let qs = new QueryStream(`
       INSERT INTO table1 
          SELECT * FROM table2
       RETURNING *;`)

const write_stream = fs.createWriteStream('file.csv');
const { parse } = require('json2csv');
const stream = client.query(qs)
let fields = [];

stream
    .on('data', data => {
         // write csv headers
         if (!fields.length) {
             fields = Object.keys(data)
             write_stream.write(fields.join(',') + '\r\n')
         }

         try {
           // write csv data
           const csv = parse(data, {header : false})
           write_stream.write(csv + '\r\n')
         } catch (err) {
           stream.close()
         }
    })
    .on('end', (end) => {
      write_stream.end()
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
       console.error(error)
    })
```

Comment: Stream usage without executing any query doesn't really answer your own question. The link that provided however, that gives you the idea of how to do it correctly.

Comment: Why re-invent the approach from the link? The code example provided is the right way to do it, and it is way simpler also.

Comment: The example you provided is bad in a number of ways: 1) It does not work with `pg-promise` streaming system, which provides generic events and handling; 2) You manually handle JSON stream formatting, which is inefficient, and can be done automatically (see my answer) 3) The solution is generally over-complicated and thus error-prone.